# bootstrap column layout, two columns, one fixed width second rest of width, broken with a responsive ad

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have two columns, one is fixed width 300px (right col), second takes the rest of width (left col). Done via flex it works. Problem is, once I put responsive ad in the left column it takes more space than is available, probably because the left column has no exact width, and the right column collapses under content.

```
<style>
.rcol {
    width: 300px;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="rcol d-none d-lg-block"></div>
</div>
```

How to fix it?

One possible solution could be set on the left column

```
width: calc(100% - 300px);
```

But it is little bit hacky. Some other solution there?

Comment: Did you try to apply `margin-right: 300px` ?

Comment: @MaxiGui not helping i tried it now

Comment: I gave 3 options

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

- Demo 1 with margin-right on the left column
- Demo 2 with max-width / width  on the left column
- Demo 3 with padding-right on the row

Demo -1

```css
.rcol {
  width: 300px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-left:1px solid black,
  height:100vh;
}
.col:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color:red;
  height:200vh;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .col:nth-of-type(1){
     margin-right: 315px; /* 300px + padding 15px; */
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row mx-0">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="rcol d-none d-lg-block">I am fixed</div>
</div>
```

Demo -2

```css
.rcol {
  width: 300px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-left:3px solid black,
  height:100vh;
}
.col:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color:red;
  height:200vh;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .col:nth-of-type(1){
    max-width: calc(100% - 315px); /* 300px + padding 15px; */
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row mx-0">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="rcol d-none d-lg-block">I am fixed</div>
</div>
```

DEMO -3

```css
.rcol {
  width: 300px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-left:1px solid black,
  height:100vh;
}
.col:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color:red;
  height:200vh;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .row-padding-300{
    padding-right: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row mx-0 row-padding-300">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="rcol d-none d-lg-block">I am fixed</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer bottom helped. (Put script of adsense in the footer)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50530706/4870273